# Handle multiple clicks when making an object move

Tags: javascript, image, offset, onmousedown

I have the following:

```
var player = $('#player');
//Checks to see which key is pressed down

$(window).on('mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log(e.offsetX + ', ' + e.offsetY);

    player.animate({
        left: e.offsetX + 'px',
        top: e.offsetY + 'px'
    }, 500);
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I click somewhere on the screen, the image moves to that position, but if I click again in the middle of my moving-animation, it's supposed to go to the last place I clicked instead of carrying out the first animation first.

[**Full fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/nCEWu/22/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `player.stop(false);` before `player.animate(...);`. It will stop currently running and queued animations of the player object.

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple clicks **you need to create a pool, an array of functions controled by another function**, so when you click at the body you'll add a new function that move the image.

Below, I show a piece of code, about how to create and push an array of functions:

```
var listRuns = [],
    ind = 0;

$('#btnRun').click(function(){
  var message = document.getElementById("txtMsg").value;

  listRuns.push(function(){
    run(message);
  });
});
```

Then, you need another function that control the execution of this array, as show below:

```
var runAll = function(){  
  if (listRuns.length>ind){
    listRuns[ind]();
    ind++; 
  }
};

var idInterval = setInterval(function(){
  runAll();
},1000);
```

So, you create a poll of executions, take a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/oqaWUbi/47/edit?js,console,output) to more detailed information.